# How do I Access an empty result in Python SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm not very familiar with Python, after a whole day trying and trying I'm fed up. I need to fill an empty Sqlite table (status) with the first entry from iterating over another table (software) to get the id from Software and enter it (among other data) into Status, and every entry with the same id updates the entry. The database is recreated every time, so I know that the tables are empty. I have to check whether there's already an entry, and there is my problem - the first check returns an empty result, how do I check if the result is empty ? I tried exists, too, but that resulted in an endless loop, although I pretty much copied from the documentation [SQLAlchemyDocumentation - Exists](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html?highlight=exists#using-exists), with one exception, I used a dictionary in the where clause instead of a class object. What is the easiest

```
def getStatusData():
    session = Session(engine)
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')  ## zum Einlesen des Formats '1 Jan 2020'
    statusList = getStatusList()
    for content in statusList:
        prev_datestring = str(content['date'] + " " + content['time'])  ## Datum und Zeit zu einem Feld zusammenfügen
        prev_date = datetime.strptime(prev_datestring, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S') ## DateTime in Pythonformat umwandeln
        resultID = session.execute(select(db.Software.id).where(db.Software.name == content['name']))
        for rows in resultID:
            id = rows.id
            resultStatID = session.execute(select(db.Status).where(db.Status.software_id == id))
            try:
               if resultStatID   #.... ?

            except:
                ("nothing here")
```

try to exist..

```
  stmt = exists().where(db.Software.name == content['name'])
        for name, in session.query(db.Software.name).filter(stmt):
            print(name)
```

Comment: With your existing `resultStatID` query, `resultStatID.first()` will return the first item it finds, and if no matching items are found it will return `None`. `.exists()` serves a different purpose and is not what you need to use here.

Comment: It many cases with python an empty result, an empty string, None - all of these are "falsey" values so very like this is what you want (exactly what you - almost - wrote) `if resultStatID:` or (to get the opposite truth value) `if not resultStatID:`

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful, consider yourself hugged (I'm female :D) . I have to admit that despite I usuallly unserstand English quite well, I sometimes have some difficulties understanding the SqlAlchemy doc, since Python is pretty new to me sometimes it takes days till I come up with a solution.